# What are some good ways to make an async web app on ruby these days?

Tags: ruby, rack, thin, eventmachine, camping

I'm looking to build a webapp with a WebSocket component, and a run of the mill rack based frontend. My initial plan was to use Camping for the frontend, running the server on thin, with a rack `config.ru` looking like this:

```
require 'rack'
require './parts/web-frontend'
require './parts/websocket'

AppStationary = Rack::File.new("./stationary")
run Rack::Cascade.new(AppWebSockets, AppWebPages, AppStationary)
```

`AppWebSockets` is being provided by websocket-rack and works great. In the absence of an `Upgrade: WebSocket` request it simply 404's and the request runs down the cascade to the camping app, `AppWebPages`.

It's becoming clear that this camping webapp inevitably requires access to IO, to talk with the CouchDB database using regular http requests. There are plenty of ways to do http requests, including some async libraries compatible with eventmachine. If I subscribe to a callback, rack returns and the page has already responded by the time I'm ready to create a response. I'd like to be able to use em-synchrony to get some concurrency via Ruby 1.9's Fibers - which I've only just gotten my head around - but cannot find any documentation on how to make use of em-synchrony with Thin.

I've encountered a webserver called Goliath which claims to be similar to thin, with em-synchrony support baked in, but it lacks a command line utility to launch and test the server and seems to require I write a different sort of file to a rackup, which is quite distasteful. It also is unclear if it would even support websocket-rack, which only specifies support for Thin currently.

What are some good ways to avoid blocking IO while still making use of familiar rack based tools like camping, and having access to WebSockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to add async support to Camping: https://gist.github.com/1192720 (see 65 for the code you'll have to use in your app). Maybe we should wrap it up in a gem or something…

Comment: Maybe we could make it nicer? def later; throw :async; end; then you can write a method: def get(var); stuff; things; --later; setup some async things; end — That it looks kinda nice, like a little separator. It'd be even nicer if it could be --later--, but ruby doesn't like that. Maybe there's some other ascii art-alike things we could use like that?

Answer (score 2):

In regards to Goliath, Goliath is based on Thin (I started with the thin code and when from there). A lot of the code has changed (e.g. using http_parser.rb instead of mongrel parser) but the original basis was Thin.

Launching the server is just a matter of executing your .rb file. The system is the same as Sinatra uses (I borrowed the code from Sinatra to make it work). You can also write you own server if you want, there are examples in the repo if you need the extra control. For us, we wanted the launching to be as simple as possible and require as few files created as possible. So, launching .rb file and using God to bringup/restart servers worked well.

Tests you write with RSpec/Test::Unit and run the test file as you normally would. The tests for Goliath will fire up the reactor and send real requests to the API from your unit tests (note, this doesn't fork, it uses EM to run the reactor in the same process as the tests). All this stuff is wrapped in a test_helper that goliath provides.

There is no rackup file with Goliath. You run the .rb file directly. The Goliath application has the middleware use commands baked straight into the .rb file. For us at PostRank, this was the easiest and clearest way to define the server. You had all of your use statements (with any extra bits they use) visible as you work on the file instead of having multiple files.  For us, this was a win, your mileage may vary.

I have no idea if websocket-rack would work but, there is a branch in the repo for baking websocket support straight into Goliath. I haven't looked at it in a while (there were some upstream bugs that got fixed that were required) but it shouldn't be too hard to get it up and running and, with the upstream fixed, merged into master.

To your question about em-synchrony and thin, you should just be able to wrap an EM.synchrony {} block around your code. The synchrony method just calls down to EM.run and wraps your block in a new fiber. If the reactor is already running EM will just execute the passed block immediately. As long as Thin has already started the reactor this should work fine.

**Update:** The websockets branch as been merged into Goliath mainline, so there is WebSocket support baked straight into Goliath if you're running from HEAD.

Comment: Thanks for the info dj2! Seeing that Goliath was built to run PostRank, and PostRank itself has been acquired by Google - does Goliath still have any commercial drive behind it? I've had the impression that google tries to move all of their products towards using Go, Python, or Java, and eventually Go and "Dart". This was one of the reasons I mostly ignored using Goliath. Eschewing Rackups made compounded those concerns as it makes switching to another server less trivial.

Comment: There are commercial companies using Goliath. See http://www.poweredbygamespy.com/2011/09/09/growing-pains-they-hurt-so-good/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Cramp - http://cramp.in ? Cramp is fully async and has an in-built websockets support.

Comment: I took a look at Cramp, but I do rather like camping, so I'd rather stick with it. Also, the name is a bit distasteful. I wouldn't feel terribly gleeful telling people my web app runs on 'cramp'.

Comment: Sigh. FWIW, I named it Cramp because async programming cramps my style.

Comment: Haha. "I won't use the technology I'm looking for because of its silly name!". Wat?